# The sign of enthalpy of formation of magnesium oxide

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, heat

I'm currently doing a lab to calculate the enthalpy of formation for $\ce{MgO}$. However at the moment me and my lab partner are having a disagreement. We've both calculated and agreed upon the same heat released in the reactions ($\pu{4.2\frac {kJ}{mol}}$ (reaction of $\ce{MgO +2HCl})$ and $\pu{7.5\frac {kJ}{mol}}$ (reaction of $\ce{Mg +2HCl}$)). Where we disagree is over how to calculate the enthalpy of reaction.

---

**My argument:**

Enthalpy is the amount of energy put into the reaction, what we measured is the heat released thus the equation should be:
$$\Delta H=-\frac{Q}{n}$$
Also, this would make sense considering our reactions were blatantly exothermic, and using this equation provides negative values.

---

**Her argument:**

The equation is simple and the teacher agreed with her results:
$$\Delta H=\frac{Q}{n}$$

---

**My question:** Who is correct?

Comment: She is right, and the Q should be negative.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are correct. Q is the change in heat for the surroundings. Thus, you have to put a negative sign in front of it to determine the change in heat for the system. If the system loses heat, the surroundings gain heat, vice versa.

Comment: @Frank, That is not correct.  Q represents the amount of heat you have to **add to the system** so that the final temperature of the products is the same as the initial temperature of the reactants.  So Q represents heat added to the system, not heat added to the surroundings.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I'm pretty sure this experiment is carried out in a calorimeter, and Q is calculated using Q = mcΔT. I feel like that would be the most reasonable method to carry out such an experiment. Also, why would you want to add heat to make the products the initial temperature instead of just measuring the temperature change?

Comment: @Frank you are correct we conducted in the reactions in a styrofoam cup, and measured the temperature change. We then used Q=mcΔT to calculate heat.

Comment: The calorimeter experiment is just a vehicle used for determining the quantity I described.  You only measure a small temperature rise because of the large thermal inertia of the calorimeter, and you use the measured rise to determine the amount of heat you would have had to add to result in the temperatures of the products being equal to the temperatures if the reactants.  (For an exothermic reaction, this would be negative)  When you learned how to use a calorimeter to measure the heat of reaction, didn't they teach you this stuff?  They should have.

Comment: I think we're talking about the same thing in opposite ways. What I'm talking about is, when you measure the temperature change in the calorimeter, and you convert that to heat, you are calculating the heat added/removed from the surroundings. In a calorimetry experiment, you measure the temperature change of water. OP even noted that the calculated Q (heat) was positive, and since the reaction was exothermic, the Q he measured was obviously the heat added to the surroundings. I think what you are talking about is the inverse of this, although I'm not completely sure what you mean.

Comment: @Frank  I stand by what I said in my earlier post.  For an exothermic reaction, the change in enthalpy is negative, and heat is removed from the system (negative Q).

Comment: Exactly. He has positive Q values from his calculations and must multiply them by -1 to get the actual ΔH, which is negative.

Comment: In thermodynamics, the **convention** is that Q represents the heat transferred *from* the surroundings *to* the system.  So, for an exothermic reaction, both Q and $Delta H$ are negative.  There is no need to multiply by -1 if the convention is followed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you've been answered in the comments already, but anyway. You are correct. In thermodynamics, enthalpy is the energy supplied to the system at constant pressure. If a reaction is accompanied by the release of heat, i.e. if it is exothermic, its $\Delta H$ is negative. If $x$ kJ is released into the calorimeter upon dissolving 1 mol of substance, resulting in the rise of calorimeter temperature, then $\Delta H_{diss} = -x$ kJ/mol.

As for the heat, depends on the type of the calorimeter, i.e. on the direction in which the heat flows. For conventional "coffee cup" calorimeter, where $Q=mC\Delta T$, $Q$ is the energy *released*, so $Q = -\Delta H$. For some power-compensated calorimeter, where you vary the heater power so as to maintain the temperature, $Q$ would be equal to the energy *supplied*. Since you have to supply excess energy ($Q>0$) to offset the endothermic reaction ($\Delta H>0$), $Q = \Delta H$.

I've heard that a long time ago, at least in some countries, there were two systems of signs for enthalpies, so-called "thermodynamic" and "thermochemical," with reversed signs in the latter. However, I haven't seen "thermochemical" one in real life, and it seems to be long since abandoned. It is not even mentioned in modern textbooks on thermodynamics. So only the thermodynamic sign system, where $\Delta H>0$ for endothermic processes, remains.